# c# assigning object values in if statement

Tags: c#, class, object, if-statement

I am reading a file and information is provided line by line (this I can't change). I want to create an object if the line has x value and if the line has y value, assign some values to the object. this proves to be very challenging. obviously I am doing something wrong.

```
if (line_split[i].Contains("LabelId"))
{
   try
   {
       gen.m_LabelId_pos.Add(multicast_ports[3], i);
       multicast my_multicast = new multicast();
   }
   catch
   {
   }
}
else if (line_split[i].Contains("TotalFrameSentCount_PerSecond"))
{
    try
    {                                    
        gen.m_TotalFrameSentCount_PerSecond_pos.Add(multicast_ports[3], i);
        // want to assign y value to the object here. but cant
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of file? csv? excel? plan text? can u put some data from file?

Comment: Are you referring to to `my_multicast` vanishing immediately after it is created?  Since you declared it as a local variable within a block statement (`{ }`) it goes out of scope as soon as the block ends.  If you want it to have a longer life it has to be declared in an outer block, though you need not assign a value there.

Comment: This isn't a question... You need to explain *what* the problem is - at the moment you're just stating that there *is* a problem. Though I do suspect that HABO hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Is it conditional in the data (exclusionary) as you have it per line?  I think we need data samples or more detailed information here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the object outside of the `if` statement, instantiate it in the `if` block and set it's value in the `else` block after you have checked that it isn't `null`. Something like this:

```
multicast my_multicast = null;
if (line_split[i].Contains("LabelId"))
{
   try
   {
       gen.m_LabelId_pos.Add(multicast_ports[3], i);
       my_multicast = new multicast();
   }
   catch
   {
   }
}
else if (line_split[i].Contains("TotalFrameSentCount_PerSecond"))
{
    try
    {                                    
        gen.m_TotalFrameSentCount_PerSecond_pos.Add(multicast_ports[3], i);
        if(my_multicast!=null)
        {
            //do something with my_multicast here
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

As an aside note, you should avoid eating your `Exceptions`, they are meant to help you if something goes wrong, this way catch block will hide them and you won't have a clue what went wrong. Use

```
catch(Exception err)
{
}
```

Comment: I think you also need to remove the `else` - otherwise `myMulticast` will always be `null` in that inner `if` statement

Comment: @Jeff Yes you are right, but I presume that he is iterating `line_split` array, in that case he hopes that he will hit the `if` before the `else if`. That is why I left it. Of course, he needs to declare the multicast variable outside the loop. If I may say this is the classical old school parsing of the string input.

Comment: @Jeff To be more clear, he wants to instantiate the object in the `if` block in the first iteration then populate the object in the `else if` block in some of the next iterations.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense then. +1